# How to do left joins with least-n-per-group query?

Tags: php, mysql, database, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to get a somewhat complicated query working and am not having any luck whatsoever.

Suppose I have the following tables:

**cart_items:**

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| item_id  | cart_id | movie_name | quantity |
+--------------------------------------------+
|     0    |    0    | braveheart |    4     |
|     1    |    0    | braveheart |    9     |
|     .    |    .    |      .     |    .     |
|     .    |    .    |      .     |    .     |
|     .    |    .    |      .     |    .     |
|     .    |    .    |      .     |    .     |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

**movies:**

```
+------------------------------+
| movie_id  | movie_name | ... |
+------------------------------+
|     0     | braveheart |  .  |
|     .     |     .      |  .  |
|     .     |     .      |  .  |
|     .     |     .      |  .  |
|     .     |     .      |  .  |
+------------------------------+
```

**pricing:**

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| id  | movie_name | quantity | price_per |
+-----------------------------------------+
|  0  | braveheart |    1     |   1.99    |
|  1  | braveheart |    2     |   1.50    |
|  2  | braveheart |    4     |   1.25    |
|  3  | braveheart |    8     |   1.00    |
|  .  |      .     |    .     |     .     |
|  .  |      .     |    .     |     .     |
|  .  |      .     |    .     |     .     |
|  .  |      .     |    .     |     .     |
|  .  |      .     |    .     |     .     |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I need to join the data from the tables, but with the added complexity that I need to get appropriate `price_per` from the `pricing` table. Only one price should be returned for each `cart_item`, and that should be the lowest price from the `pricing` table where the `quantity` for the cart item is at least the quantity in the `pricing` table.

So, the query should return for each item in `cart_items` the following:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| item_id | movie_name | quantity | price_per |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Example 1:

Variable passed to the query: cart_id = 0. Return:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| item_id | movie_name | quantity | price_per |
+---------------------------------------------+
|    0    | braveheart |    4     |   1.25    |
|    1    | braveheart |    9     |   1.00    |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Note that this is a minimalist example and that additional data will be pulled from the tables mentioned (particularly the movies table).

How could this query be composed? I have tried using left joins and subqueries, but the difficult part is getting the price and nothing I have tried has worked.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

I think this is similar to what I have working with my "real" tables:

```
SELECT t1.item_id, t2.movie_name, t1.quantity
FROM cart_items t1
LEFT JOIN movies t2 ON t2.movie_name = t1.movie_name
WHERE t1.cart_id = 0
```

Assuming I wrote that correctly (I quickly tried to "port over" my real query), then the output would currently be:

```
+---------------------------------+
| item_id | movie_name | quantity |
+---------------------------------+
|    0    | braveheart |    4     |
|    1    | braveheart |    9     |
+---------------------------------+
```

The trouble I'm having is joining the price at a certain quantity for a movie. I simply cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: please post your closest attempt.  otherwise this reads as a doitforme.com request.

Comment: OK. Everything I posted was simplified, but I will try to "port over" my current query.

Comment: @Randy - OK, I did it. It doesn't really make sense because t2.movie_name could also be gotten from cart_items, but as I mentioned this example is simplified so I would really be getting more information from t2 (movies). The part that stumps me is how to add the price.

Comment: @Randy - And by the way, I don't consider this a doitforme.com request as I've been trying to get this to work for over two straight hours.

Comment: i don't doubt you - but all too many posts read like a homework with no effort poste.. glad you edited - looks like it helped in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.item_id, t1.movie_name, t1.quantity, t2.price_per
FROM cart_items t1
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT c.quantity, c.movie_name, IF(p.price_per IS NOT NULL, MAX(p.price_per), MIN(p2.price_per)) AS `price_per`
            FROM cart_items c
                LEFT JOIN pricing p 
                    ON p.movie_name = c.movie_name 
                    AND p.quantity >= c.quantity
                LEFT JOIN pricing p2
                    ON p2.movie_name = c.movie_name 
                    AND p2.quantity < c.quantity
            GROUP BY c.quantity, c.movie_name
        ) t2 ON t2.movie_name = t1.movie_name AND t2.quantity = t1.quantity
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/072e8

regards.

Comment: Wow, that's really complicated :-)